# Batch conversion of PVR to JPEG (or similar)

Tags: textures

The command line [PVRTexTool](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrtextool.asp) works very well for getting textures into a PVR format, but I need a way of going the opposite directions. Does anyone know of a good command line tool (or GUI with a batch mode) that will convert a PowerVR texture to a more common image format (like JPEG or PNG?)

Comment: I think http://superuser.com is a better place to ask.

Comment: I'll give it a try, PVR just doesn't get much use outside of games :)

Answer (score 3):

Inside one of the folders of [PVRTexTool](http://community.imgtec.com/developers/powervr/) you find PVRTexToolCLI.exe, that is the command-line version of it. You can use a batch command on it like this:

```
for %f in (*.pvr) do PVRTexToolCLI.exe -i "%f" -d -f r8g8b8a8
```

Comment: `An error occurred in PVRTexTool: Unsupported input file format: pvr`

Answer (score 2):

I do it in 3 steps:

1. PVRTexToolCLI -dds -fDXT1 -iX.pvr -oX.dds
2. ImageMagick X.dds X.png (or X.jpg)
3. rm X.dds

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/script/index.php) - it seems to do everything, and has a good command line interface.

Comment: Apparently ImageMagick doesn't support PVR (here's a [list of supported formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php))

Answer (score 1):

I just used [Texture Packer](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) to do just as you ask:

```
for file in *.pvr.ccz; do
  /Applications/TexturePacker.app/Contents/MacOS/TexturePacker $file --sheet ${file%.pvr.ccz}.png --texture-format png --data ${file%.pvr.ccz}.plist
done
```

It gives you a PNG and a plist of the sprite data.

It also runs on most platforms, so even if you're not on a mac something similar should still work.

Comment: in texture packer comand line tool if i typed above coomand.. its ayind no such a dirctory.. can u explain a little more...

Answer (score 0):

"[Image Converter Plus](http://www.imageconverterplus.com/how-to-convert/pvr_jpg.html)" can convert PVR to JPG and PNG images. You can select and convert multiple images at same time.

Comment: Note: Windows only and not free.